# Formating Cells to only display characters after X number of Characters

Tags: excel, vba

Instead of receiving the first 12 character from the right, what's needed is the same cell without the first 12 characters.

```
Dim arrData As Variant, LastRow As Long, i As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Long List 15032019") 'change the name of the sheet to the one you are doing the code

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        arrData = .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, 3) Like "Bus*" Then
                arrData(i, 1) = "BU CRM"
            Else
                arrData(i, 1) = "CSI ACE"
            End If
            If arrData(i, 3) Like "CSI*" Or arrData(i, 3) = vbNullString Then
                arrData(i, 2) = vbNullString
                Else: arrData(i, 2) = Right(arrData(i, 3), 12)
            End If
        Next i
        .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value = arrData

         End With
```

i.e. If C3 = "Example (ID:15654534)" then B3 = "(ID:15654534)" or If C3 = "Example (ID:152)" then B3 = "(ID:152)"

I did attempt using Left or -12. But the outcome was not what I needed.
I hope that this clarifies my question.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. In your post you say *I want my cell to be the last 14 characters instead* but later on @QHarr's ansswer, you say *I want column 2 = column 3 without the first X character in this case would be "Example". So if C3 is "Example (ID:15654534)" then B3 "(ID:15654534)"or If C3 is "Example (ID:152)" then B3 "(ID:152)"* and that's completely different. Please, edit your question, adding exactly what you want, the input, the expected output and what you have tried. Help the community to help you out :)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will do so now. As you can imagine I am quiet new to VBA and this is my first project. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a regex. In this case you would have

```
arrData(i,2) =  GetId(arrData(i, 3) , "ID:\d+")
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim items(), item As Variant
    items = Array("Example (ID:15654534)", "Example (ID:152)")
    For Each item In items
        Debug.Print GetId(item, "ID:\d+")
    Next
End Sub
Public Function GetId(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As String
    Dim matches As Object, iMatch As Object, arrMatches(), i As Long
    i = 1
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = sPattern
        If .test(inputString) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(inputString)
            ReDim arrMatches(1 To matches.Count)
            For Each iMatch In matches
                arrMatches(i) = iMatch.Value
                i = i + 1
            Next iMatch
        Else
            GetId = "No match"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
    GetId = arrMatches(1)
End Function
```

Comment: So my code in column 3, has two possibilites. It gives me "Example (ID:15654534)" or "Example (ID:152)". The goal is column to display only the "(ID:XXX)"

Comment: you want only the shorter?

Comment: Both, I want column 2 = column 3 without the first X character in this case would be "Example". So if C3 is "Example (ID:15654534)" then B3 "(ID:15654534)"or If C3 is "Example (ID:152)" then B3 "(ID:152)"

Comment: I don't see a difference. You grab all the string in both cases. Sounds like you want a regex

Comment: @QHarr, reading previous comment of OP, when he/she says *"Example (ID:152)" then B3 "(ID:152)"*, I think OP needs to include both parenthesis in result

Comment: @QHarr This is the first project I'm working on, so I apologies that I do not quiet understand your code.

Comment: add the function to your project and when looping the array use arrData(i,2) =  GetId(arrData(i, 3) , "ID:\d+")

Comment: If, as @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns correctly mentions, you want the brackets then change the pattern to "\(ID:\d+\)"  instead of "ID:\d+"

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: @QHarr, would you kindly look at my new code? I appreciate all your effort to assist me.

Comment: Else: arrData(i, 2) = GetId(arrData(i, 3),  "(ID:\d+)")

Comment: Did you try the above?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without VBA, but only if input is the same structure. Your data now is:

*text(idnumber)* and you want to obtain only part *(idnumber*) including both parenthesis.

**This formula will work ONLY as long as data structure is the same**. If input changes something, it could not work properly (For example, if first parenthesis is missing, it won't work properly).

The formula I've used is this one:

```
=MID(C1;SEARCH("(";C1;1);SEARCH(")";C1)-SEARCH("(";C1;1)+1)
```

My data example:

[image]

Hope you can adap it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did use a similar question previously. But for this particular task I'm in need of using VBA instead.